# grammar rules file to simulate turing machine to accept a language

Tags: python, grammar, turing-machines

I have to create a grammar rules file to be used with a python script to accept certain strings.

The grammar:

```
Define a type 0 grammar that simulates a Turing Machine computation
to accept the language (w w | w ∊ (0 + 1)*}
```

The script (has a gui component to make running easier):

```
# Read in re-writing rules
#
start_symbol = 'S'
rules = []
def  browse():
    global start_symbol, rules
    start_symbol = 'S'
    rules = []
    fn_rules = askopenfilename(title="Select rules file", filetypes=[("*.TXT", "*.txt")])
    f_rules = open(fn_rules, "r")

    for line in f_rules.readlines():
        line = line.split()
        if len(line) < 2:
            if len(line) == 1 and len(line[0]) == 1:
                start_symbol = line[0]
            continue
        rules.append((line[0], line[-1]))

    f_rules.close()
    print(rules)

def init_str():
    tape.set('_' + start_symbol + tape.get() + '_')
```

Thinking about my problem logically, I've deduced I need to do the following steps with my turing machine (For example, on input 10111011):

```
1: Place an end marker at each end of the string:
$10111011$

2: Move the end markers inward till they meet in the middle
 and mark the middle:
1011x1011

3: Go back and forth matching and crossing off symbols of the
 two strings.
```

My only question here is how to implement this. Here is an example grammar rules file for palindromes:

```
L
_L0 → __A
_L1 → __B

0L → L0
1L → L1

A0 → 0A
A1 → 1A

B0 → 0B
B1 → 1B

0A_ → L__
1B_ → L__

_L_ → _x_
_A_ → _x_
_B_ →_ x_
```

From my understanding of the program, it reads left to right, and apparently just splits each line on whitespace and uses the first string as the left side and the last string on the line as the right side. However, I'm not sure if that's correct. Code updated

Comment: If the GUI is not pertinent to your problem, take it out. See the [mcve] guidance in the [help].

Comment: My mistake @tripleee, updated the post.